# Tooltip/mouseover text in an AnyLogic simulation user interface screen?

Tags: java, anylogic

I would like to know if it is possible implement tooltip (mouse over) text within an AnyLogic simulation, whereby the simulation user can hover the mouse over a Radio Button or Edit Box, for example, and get context dependent help message.

I note that the AnyLogic IDE provides this for (some of) the palette icons to assist the developer, so there is support in Java presumably using `setToolTipText()`, but is such a feature available also to the simulation model user?

If this is do-able, an AnyLogic-specific example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible anymore since AnyLogic UI is *not* using Java anymore (since they switched to web-based animation).

Unfortunately, we are bound to what AnyLogic provides us for UI capability. A while ago, they said they would add a "on hover" field for UI components but haven't yet. Do push them (support@anylogic.com) to keep this on their agenda, I would love that as well.

PS: Previously (AL7), you could use a `MouseListener` class

PPS: (ad) We have developed a UI library that gives you similar capability. Not hovering but standardized help messages similar to mobile app notifications: http://materialdesignforanylogic.com/